# Create java Parameterized Type on the fly

Tags: java, generics, reflection

How to create a `java.lang.reflect.Type` of type `List<T>` on the fly if I know `T` is of certain type like `String.class` or `Integer.class`?

Comment: For what would you need that?

Comment: Hmm, I may have misunderstood your question. Did you want a `List`, the `Type` of a `List` instance, or to actually _create_ (`new`) a `Type` instance?

Answer (score 4):

Java parameterized types are subject to [type erasure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_erasure) so that generic types are lost at runtime. This means that, at runtime, a `List<String>` is indistinguishable from a `List<Integer>` or a `List<Object>`, without inspecting the elements in the list.

All this to say, you don't need to worry about the parameterized type at all. You can just create a `List`.

Comment: This does not really answer the question.